# button component with BUILT-IN disable / re-enable (PREVENT DOUBLE SUBMIT!)

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular-cli

Is it just a good rule of thumb to handle all 'disable' validation logic on the form component itself?  Does that sound right??

I'm really just trying to find a way to share the 'disable' logic across the application without repeating it in every form component, but i guess that is the proper way to do things?? Can someone verify this??

I would like to create a reusable submit button component.
This submit button component should act like any other submit button component, except for one thing...

The submit button needs to "disable itself" after being clicked.
That should be easy enough right.  However, the rub here is that the button also needs to "re-enable itself" after the "call" is 100% completed. (In case there is an error, or the application needs to allow another action after the first is completed, etc).

I would like 100% of "that" logic to exist inside of the component so I can easily reuse it everywhere in the application.

I thought it would be kinda easy, but I think I'm still missing something...
I guess the idea would be to use an @Input() preferably (or maybe Output) in order to pass in some "async callback type of thing" to the button control itself...

That way the button could react to the "async callback type of thing" completing and use the callback handler to re-enable itself.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an abstract class which I use all the time for this exact case:

```
import { ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';

export abstract class FormBase<T = any> {
    @Input() isSubmitting: boolean;

    @Output('onSubmit') _submit = new EventEmitter<T>();

    @ViewChild(FormGroupDirective, { static: true })
    ngForm: FormGroupDirective;

    @ViewChild('submitButton', { static: true }) button: ElementRef;

    form: FormGroup;

    onSubmit(): void {
        if (this.isFormValid()) this._submit.emit(this.getFormValue());
    }

    submit(): void {
        if (!this.button || !this.button.nativeElement) return;

        this.button.nativeElement.click();
    }

    reset(value?: any) {
        this.ngForm.resetForm(value);
    }

    isFormValid(): boolean {
        return this.form.valid;
    }

    getFormValue(): T {
        return this.form.value;
    }

    shouldDisable(): boolean {
        return (
            this.isSubmitting ||
            ((this.form.invalid || this.form.pending) &&
                (this.ngForm ? this.ngForm.submitted : true))
        );
    }
}
```

component.ts

```
import { FormBase } from 'path';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class FormComponent extends FormBase {
    constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        super();
        this.form = formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }
}
```

component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="username" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="password" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <button [disabled]="shouldDisable()" mat-flat-button color="primary">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Your form components basically extend from this class which should work 99% of the time. If your component needs some very specific functionality like changing when the button becomes disabled or something else, you can simply override the methods in the FormComponent.